# IF, AND, and ISBLANK statement?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to find out how to do a formula as the following:

```
=IF(AND([@1Date]=[@[2DATE]],ISBLANK([@NUMBER]])),"No","Yes")
```

Basically I am trying to see if two dates are equal to one another AND if the NUMBER column is blank. I want to be returned a "No" or a "Yes", if the opposite.

When I do this, I am only getting "No", but I know there should be both being returned.
What is wrong with my formula?

Answer (score 2):

Table Name Reference Brackets not matched properly:

`=IF(AND([@1Date]=[@2DATE],ISBLANK([@NUMBER])),"No","Yes")`